# In how many outcomes can we get 5 balls in 10 balls in any order?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

In order to enter the Lottery, you choose five different numbers in the range 1 to
53, and write them, in an order of your choice, on an entry form.
'''
You win Prize 3 if your five numbers occur anywhere within the ten-number selection
made by the machine (including those positions for which you win Prize 2), and in any
order. In how many of the outcomes of part (a) do you win Prize 3?
'''

So our teacher has told us to do:

1. fix 5 balls (1 way)
2. 48C5 to choose another 5 balls.
3. Mix them all up to the first 5 fixed balls can occur anywhere (10!)

so we do 48C5*10!.

My question is why do we use combinatorics and NOT permutations? since on the previous example :
'''
You win Prize 2 if the first five balls selected by the machine match the five numbers
you chose, and are arranged in any order (including that for which you win Prize
'''
we used 
Fix 5 balls.

choose another 5 (48P5)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: What is " outcome of part (a)"?

Comment: it is 6.21*10^12

Comment: Order of balls does not matter for winning the prize so it's combinations.

Comment: "it is 6.21*10^12" was a response to my comment?

Comment: [Combinatorics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorics) is a branch of mathematics concerned with the enumeration, existence, construction, and optimization of finite structures.  What you meant to ask is why we use [combinations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination) rather than permutations.  The number of combinations $\binom{n}{k} = \frac{n!}{k!(n - k)!}$ is the number of ways we can choose a subset of $k$ elements from a set with $n$ elements.  The order in which the elements are selected does not matter for a combination, while it does matter for a permutation.